# Buildout error: couldn't find a distribution for package xyz

Tags: plone, buildout

I am trying to install getpaid for plone and my buidout returns:

```
Error: Couldn't find a distribution for 'yoma.batching==0.2.2-getpaid'.
```

My buildout includes:

```
find-links =
    http://getpaid.googlecode.com/files/yoma.batching-0.2.2-getpaid.zip
```

...and that link works.

How can I resolve this kind of problem?

Comment: That procedure worked smoothly here. Could you post your buildout config so we can see what's going on? Maybe there's an "allow-hosts" variable that blocks any unknown host?

Comment: This my buildout http://www.pastie.org/3044078

Comment: I should add that I have tried at different times over 2 days.

Comment: You have find-links defined twice so the second if overriding the first.

Comment: Yeah, exactly. You can either merge the 2 definitions o in the second one you have to use `+=` instead of `=`.

Answer (score 4):

Add this line to your buildout.

```
index = https://pypi.python.org/simple
```

index

```
An alternate index location.

This can be a local directory name or an URL. It can be a flat collection of distributions, but should be a “simple” index, with subdirectories for distribution project names containing distributions for those projects.

If this isn’t set, then https://pypi.python.org/simple/ is used.
```

From documentation of buildout.

Answer (score 2):

Your [buildout](http://www.pastie.org/3044078) has **find-links** defined twice. The second **find-links** is overriding the first one (that has the proper link to yoma.batching).

You can merge the two find-links in one:

```
find-links =
    http://getpaid.googlecode.com/files/hurry.workflow-0.9.2-getpaid.zip
    http://getpaid.googlecode.com/files/ore.viewlet-0.2.3-getpaid.zip
    http://getpaid.googlecode.com/files/yoma.batching-0.2.2-getpaid.zip
    http://dist.plone.org
    http://download.zope.org/ppix/
    http://download.zope.org/distribution/
    http://effbot.org/downloads
    http://dist.plone.org/thirdparty/PILwoTk-1.1.6.4.tar.gz
```

The answer were on the comments.

Answer (score 0):

PyPI's CDN [Fastly has recently been running rolling brownouts for HTTP clients that don't support SNI](https://github.com/pypa/pypi-support/issues/978), Server Name Indication (a security technology). This applies to old Python 2 versions (2.7.13 is fine) and [old setuptools versions (37.0.0 should work)](https://github.com/pypa/pypi-support/issues/978#issuecomment-810528453). So make sure those were upgraded. In our case we found a CI server running setuptools 33.

You can follow updates at [status.python.org](https://status.python.org/incidents/hzmjhqsdjqgb). On 3 May 2021, support for old clients will be removed.